# MySQL SELECT x FROM a WHERE NOT IN ( SELECT x FROM b ) - Unexpected result

Tags: sql, mysql

I expect the result of the third query below to contain id=732. It doesn't. Why is that?

```
mysql> SELECT id FROM match ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 ;
+------------+
|         id |
+------------+
|        732 | 
|        730 | 
|        655 | 
|        458 | 
|        456 | 
+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT id FROM email ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 ;
+------------+
|         id |
+------------+
|        731 | 
|        727 | 
|        725 | 
|        724 | 
|        723 | 
+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM match WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM email ) ;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

There are three NULL entries in table email.id, and no NULL entries in match.id.

The full table / queries can be seen at http://pastebin.ca/1462094

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From [**documentation**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html):

> To comply with the `SQL` standard, `IN`  returns `NULL` not only if the expression on the left hand side is `NULL`, but also if no match is found in the list and one of the expressions in the list is `NULL`.

This is exactly your case.

Both `IN` and `NOT IN` return `NULL` which is not an acceptable condition for `WHERE` clause.

Rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    match m
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  1
        FROM    email e
        WHERE   e.id = m.id
        )
```

Comment: Is it the OP's case? My understanding was that the "if no match is found and one of the expressions in the list is NULL" isn't the case since 732 should be found, thereby invalidating that clause, right?

Comment: @Eric: 732 is not found in emails.

Answer (score 52):

... or if you really want to use `NOT IN` you can use

```
SELECT * FROM match WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id FROM email WHERE id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: This worked for me, wanted to create a dropdown of "meter types" which had not already been selected, ie had no records in second table

Comment: I prefer this answer. Didn't know the "where id is not null null" was necessary to make the "not in" query work.

Answer (score 8):

I'm a little out of touch with the details of how MySQL deals with nulls, but here's two things to try:

```
SELECT * FROM match WHERE id NOT IN 
    ( SELECT id FROM email WHERE id IS NOT NULL) ;

SELECT
    m.*
FROM
    match m
    LEFT OUTER JOIN email e ON
        m.id = e.id
        AND e.id IS NOT NULL
WHERE
    e.id IS NULL
```

The second query looks counter intuitive, but it does the join condition and then the where condition. This is the case where joins and where clauses are not equivalent.

Comment: My understanding is that using a left outer join is better for performance as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some SQL that actually make sense:

```
SELECT m.id FROM match m LEFT JOIN email e ON e.id = m.id WHERE e.id IS NULL
```

Simple is always better.

Comment: Even though it's not intuitive, that's actually the most efficient solution.