# MySQL NOT IN from another column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to run a mysql query to select all rows from a table `films` where the value of the `title` column does not exist anywhere in all the values of another column (`collection`).

Here is a simplified version of my table with content:

```
mysql> select * from films;
+----+--------------+--------------+
| id | title        | collection   |
+----+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | Collection 1 | NULL         |
|  2 | Film 1       | NULL         |
|  3 | Film 2       | Collection 1 |
+----+--------------+--------------+
```

Here is my query:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM films WHERE title NOT IN (SELECT collection FROM films);
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

In this example, I would want to select the rows with titles `Film 1` and `Film 2`, but my query is returning no rows.

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `films` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `collection` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: The reason you're not retuning any rows is because NULL isn't being considered in the result set. I have a sneaking suspicion if you replace NULL with an empty string, this may fix your problem.

Comment: @JoshuaBurns I tested this and it doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: `Not in (Set containing null)` always returns no rows.

Comment: This is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001144/mysql-select-x-from-a-where-not-in-select-x-from-b-unexpected-result

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM films 
WHERE title NOT IN (SELECT collection FROM films where collection is not null);
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76278/1

Comment: +1 I think you posted this while I was editing mine with the `IN` version as well

Comment: Thanks, I'm accepting yours because it's the first correct answer (and the one I'm going to use). Could you explain why the `is not null` makes it work?

Comment: *is not null* is needed because the semantic specification of *not in* requires that the set can't contain any null element.  See documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html where it says *To comply with the SQL standard, IN returns NULL not only if the expression on the left hand side is NULL, but also if no match is found in the list and one of the expressions in the list is NULL.*

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM films f1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT collection 
                  FROM films f2
                  WHERE f1.title = f2.collection);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92eb7/15)

If you want to use `IN` then you will want to look for values that are `NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM films 
WHERE title NOT IN (SELECT collection 
                    FROM films
                    WHERE collection is not null);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92eb7/18)

The result for both is:

```
| ID |  TITLE |   COLLECTION |
------------------------------
|  2 | Film 1 |       (null) |
|  3 | Film 2 | Collection 1 |
```

The problem with your current query is that -- stealing from [@Quassnoi's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001144/mysql-select-x-from-a-where-not-in-select-x-from-b-unexpected-result):

> *Both `IN` and `NOT IN` return `NULL` which is not an acceptable condition for `WHERE` clause.*

Since the `null` value is being returned by your subquery you want to specifically exclude it.

Comment: @jessica you requested additional details on why you need to filter out `null` values from the subquery -- see [this link](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null). Or even this [question answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001144/mysql-select-x-from-a-where-not-in-select-x-from-b-unexpected-result) by the same person who wrote those articles.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/784dc/2)

Query:

```
select a.id, a.planid
from one a
left join one b
on a.planid <> b.iid
where not (b.iid is null)
group by b.id
;
```

Results: based on the sample table I used.

```
ID      PLANID
t15     1
j18     2
```

### EDIT TO ADD : HERE WITH OP SCHEMA

```
select b.id, b.title
from opschema b
inner join opschema a
on b.title <> a.collection
or b.collection <> a.title
group by b.id 
;
```

[OP SHCEMA SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00df9/1)

```
ID  TITLE
2   Film 1
3   Film 2
```

Comment: This answer doesn't follow OP's schema.

Comment: @njk my logic is correct though :) I have also added OP's schema.

Comment: @Jessica please give a try on this one as well and comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option using an outer join

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM films f LEFT OUTER JOIN films ff
ON f.title = ff.collection
WHERE ff.collection IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reservation_tables` (
  `res_table_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `res_table_name` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `date_time` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `partyhall_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `flag` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`res_table_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;


INSERT INTO `reservation_tables` (`res_table_id`, `res_table_name`, `date_time`, `partyhall_id`, `flag`) VALUES
(1, 1, '2014-08-17 12:00 am', 7, '1'),
(2, 2, '2014-08-17 12:00 am', 7, '1'),
(3, 3, '2014-08-18 12:00 am', 8, '1'),
(4, 4, '2014-08-18 12:00 am', 8, '1'),
(5, 1, '2014-08-25 12:00 am', 12, '1'),
(6, 2, '2014-08-25 12:00 am', 12, '1'),
(7, 3, '2014-08-20 12:00 am', 23, '1'),
(8, 4, '2014-08-20 12:00 am', 23, '1');
```

Ι had to select available table name for `matching date_time`

Example `select available table_name where date_time = 2014-08-18 12:00 am.`

solution query is:
im sure this works well

```
SELECT distinct res_table_name FROM reservation_tables WHERE `res_table_name` NOT IN   
(SELECT `res_table_name` FROM reservation_tables where `date_time` = '2014-08-17 12:00 am')
```