# SQL in MariaDB How to use data from 2 columns to select values from another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

The specific question is select rollno from class table who where present in dbms and not present in maths.

```
rollno sts sub
1      1    dbms
1      0    maths
2      1    dbms
2      0    maths
3      0    dbms
3      1    maths
4      0    dbms
4      0    maths
5      1    dbms
5      1    maths
```

Comment: Sounds a lot like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL NOT IN from another column in the same table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245671/mysql-not-in-from-another-column-in-the-same-table)

Comment: yes but it always returns the wrong value by this statement :
select rollno from gaurav where sts=1 AND(sub='dbms' OR NOT(sub='maths'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select rollno
from mytable
group by rollno
having sum(sub = 'dbms' and sts = 1) > 0
   and sum(sub = 'maths' and sts = 1) = 0
```

This uses the fact that true evaluates to 1 and false evaluates to 0 in MySQL.

- `sum(sub = 'dbms' and sts = 1)` finds number of rows where sub is dbms for the given rollno, which must be atleast 1
- `sum(sub = 'maths' and sts = 1)` finds number of rows where sub is maths for the given rollno, which must be 0.

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/UTK43251)

Comment: this doesnot return any value, Please have a look at my table in the pic i have attached

Comment: @TheImaginaryGuy - When you say "present in dbms" do you mean has a row with sub as dbms and sts = 1? If so, updated the answer and added a demo as well

Comment: Yes I mean the same.Thanx for the demo.and one more thing is that i also want to display that the rollno's whose sts is 0 is maths

Comment: i mean it should print

Answer (score 0):

you could use two subselect with id and not in

```
select roolno
from my_table 
where sub in (select roolno from my_table  where sub ='dbms')
and sub not in (select roolno from my_table  where sub ='maths' )
```

Comment: its is not returning any value

Comment: this mean that your data don't allow  a proper result .....   where is your dara sample ?