# Insert WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that I regularly update by inserting a csv file which is dumped from another source.  This file contains exisiting data in my table as well as new data.  What I currently do is delete the contents of the table that relate to the data dump and re-import using the following php script:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$handle = fopen($file,"r");

while(($fileop = fgetcsv($handle,1000, ",")) !== false)
{
    $player_id = $fileop[1];
    $fixture_id = $fileop[3];
    $opponent = $fileop[6];
    $home_away = $fileop[7];
    $team_id = $fileop[8];
    $season_id = $fileop[9];
    $fixture_date = $fileop[11];
    $runs = $fileop[15];
    $sixes = $fileop[17];
    $fours = $fileop[16];
    $how_out = $fileop[25];
    $wk_catches = $fileop[26];
    $fielder_catches = $fileop[27];
    $fielder_stumpings = $fileop[28];
    $_fielder_runouts = $fileop[29];
    $wickets = $fileop[30];
    $bowling_runs = $fileop[31];
    $balls_bowled = $fileop[32];
    $maidens = $fileop[33];
    $bowled = $fileop[37];
    $caught = $fileop[38];
    $lbw = $fileop[39];
    $stumped = $fileop[40];
    $position = $fileop[47];

    $sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO stats_game (player_id, fixture_id, opponent, home_away, team_id, season_id, fixture_date, runs, fours, sixes, how_out, wk_catches, fielder_catches, fielder_stumpings, _fielder_runouts, wickets, bowling_runs, balls_bowled, maidens, bowled, caught, lbw, stumped, position) VALUES ('$player_id', '$fixture_id', '$opponent', '$home_away', '$team_id', '$season_id', '$fixture_date', '$runs', '$fours', '$sixes', '$how_out', '$wk_catches', '$fielder_catches', '$fielder_stumpings', '$_fielder_runouts', '$wickets', '$bowling_runs', '$balls_bowled', '$maidens', '$bowled', '$caught', '$lbw', '$stumped', '$position') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from stats_game)");
}
if($sql){
    echo 'data uploaded successfully';}else{
        die(mysql_error());
}
}

?>
```

What I really want to do is to just insert the data that does not currently exsit in the table.  I have tried to do this via adding:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from stats_table)
```

but this is throwing a syntax error...

Could you please suggest a method of doing this.

Comment: So you want to check the exact duplicate that matches by all columns?

Comment: Yes, because the data dump has no primary key and all of the columns are capable of having duplicate values

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

```
Insert ...On Duplicate key update
```

Please refer to the following link it may help you

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Or You can see this post

- [How to insert if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361340/how-to-insert-if-not-exists-in-mysql?rq=1)

Hope that would help ! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you want this:

```
WHERE field NOT IN (SELECT field FROM stats_table) ;
```

Also you may take a look at 
[MySQL SELECT x FROM a WHERE NOT IN ( SELECT x FROM b ) - Unexpected result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001144/mysql-select-x-from-a-where-not-in-select-x-from-b-unexpected-result)